# What's the difference between "Thing thing;" and "Thing thing = Thing();", and when should I use one over the other?

Tags: c++, variables, object

I don't understand the difference between the two following statements:

```
Thing thing;

Thing thing = Thing();
```

Both create a `Thing` object and put it in the variable `thing`, right? If so, two questions:

1- What are the technical differences between the two?

2- When should I use one over the other?

Please note:

A- I am not using C++ 11.

B- New to C++, please use newbie-friendly words.

Comment: First one default-initializes. Second one effectively value-initializes.

Comment: There should be a duplicate of this..

Comment: See [cppreference's initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) page for more.

Comment: @remyabel: C++11? Do you mean C++03? Value-initialization was added in 03.

Comment: `using Thing = int`...

Answer (score 4):

```
Thing thing;
```

is default-initialization. If `Thing` is a class type, it calls the default constructor of `Thing`, and that's it.

```
Thing thing = Thing();
```

value-initializes a temporary `Thing` and then copies/moves that temporary into `thing`. In practice compilers will elide the copy/move, making it effectively a value-initialization, but this still requires a copy/move constructor to be available. The `= Thing();` syntax is needed to get value-initialization semantics because `Thing thing();` is the vexing parse.<sup>*</sup>

The difference between value-initialization and default-initialization is that in some cases (the exact cases [depend on the version of the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), but a non-union class type with no user-provided constructors, and non-class non-array types, along with arrays of these types qualify in all versions), value-initialization will zero-initialize first before calling the default constructor.

Using the second version is helpful if `Thing` can be a non-class (e.g., in a template) or is a class type that would get the zero-initialization treatment (e.g., a POD class) and you want it to have well-defined values.

<sub><sup>*</sup>`Thing thing{};` is subtly different in initialization semantics from plain value-initialization in C++14.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Two questions: 1- In general should I just use `Thing t;`? 2- In what cases should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: @AvivCohn I would use the first unless you have reason to use the second, and use the second when `Thing` has no user-provided constructor and you want its members to have well-defined values.

Comment: TC's suggestion is something you should do rarely, if at all. I it makes for fragile code to rely on the user specifying whether the object is initialized or contains uninitialzed values.  If the object is supposed to always represent some sort of state, then it should have a constructor which initializes all of its members.

Comment: @MattMcNabb POD classes. Can't have user-provided default constructors.

Comment: @TC Yes I'm aware of that. I'm suggesting to generally avoid a design that relies on PODs being initialized by this syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The notation

```
Thing thing = Thing();
```

which does a copy initialization, could be used in C++03 template code to effectively default-construct a `Thing`. The thing is that this works also for built-in types `Thing` such as `int`. This contorted notation because writing `Thing thing();` just declares a function (a special case of “the most vexing parse”).

In C++11 one can instead write

```
Thing thing{};
```

An alternative technique in C++03 was to wrap `Thing` in a `struct`, like this:

```
struct Initialized_thing
{
    Thing thing;
    Initialized_thing(): thing() {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the compiler can issue an error for the second definition if the copy or move constructor is not accessible. For example they might be defined as private or deleted.

```
Thing thing;

Thing thing = Thing(); // there may be a compiler error
```

For example consider the following programs

```
int main() 
{
    class A
    {
    private:
        A( const A & );
    public:
        A() {}  
    };

    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

The program above will be compiled successfuly while the program below will not be compiled (if only the compiler is not for example MS VC++ 2010)

```
int main() 
{
    class A
    {
    private:
        A( const A & );
    public:
        A() {}  
    };

    A a = A();

    return 0;
}
```

The other difference that in this statement

```
A a;
```

a is default initialized

while in this statement

```
A a = A();
```

a is value initialized.

From the C++ Standard

> 2 The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier or
>   typename-specifier for a non-array complete object type or the
>   (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates a prvalue of the specified
>   type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an
>   object of type T; no initialization is done for the void() case.

Consider another example

```
int main() 
{
    class A
    {
        int x;
    };

    A a1;
    A a2 = A();     

    return 0;
}
```

For a1 value of x will be unspecified while for s2 value of x will be equal to 0.

Comment: So generally, I should use `A a;`, not `A a = A();`?

Comment: @Aviv Cohn It depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

As others have written the syntax

```
Thing obj;
```

will [default-initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) your object, while the syntax

```
Thing obj = Thing();
```

will [value-initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) your object.

The second syntax causes more stuff to be involved:

- A move/copy constructor should be accessible
- A temporary is value-initialized
- Copy elision takes place

They usually serve different purposes and although the first one is the most commonly used to initialize an object, the latter is different in the value-initialization meaning.

I recommend reading the documentation for the differences between value and default initialization, anyway a simple example to show the differences is the following:

```
class Thing {
  public:

  int data;

  Thing() {
      cout << "default ctor" << endl;
  }

  Thing(const Thing&) {
      cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
  }

  const Thing& operator=(const Thing&) {
      cout << "operator=" << endl;
      return *this;
  }
};

struct Thingy {
    int data;  
};

int main() {
  cout << is_pod<Thing>::value << endl; // Thing is NOT pod

  Thing thing; // Calls default constructor
  cout << thing.data << endl; // Garbage

  Thing thing2 = Thing(); // Copy elision is able to optimize this (standard-defined 12.8/31). Anyway a copy/move constructor must be accessible
  cout << thing2.data << endl; // Garbage

  // -----------------------------------------------------

  cout << is_pod<Thingy>::value << endl; // Thingy IS pod

  Thingy thingy1;
  cout << thingy1.data << endl; // garbage

  Thingy thingy2 = Thingy();
  cout << thingy2.data << endl; // zero-initialized!
}
```

The above code will print

```
0 // Not a POD
default ctor
-1326900592 // garbage
default ctor
-1326900592 // garbage
// ---------------------------
1 // POD
-1326900592 // garbage
0           // zero-initialized
```